# How to find out which OpenGL functions I can use with OpenGL 3.3 video card?

Tags: opengl, version, nvidia, video-card

I am about to start learning OpenGL with the book : OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition. I am an absolute beginner, so if my question will seem "strange", it means I need some extra explanations.

The book states :

> This book covers version 4.3 of the OpenGL specification.

But my video card ( Nvidia GeForce 9500GT ) supports only OpenGL 3.3 ( that is what I found when checking [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) ).

My question is : When learning from the book, how do I know which functions and methods explained in the book I can use with my video card, and which ones I can't ?

Comment: This depends on more than just the version of OpenGL that your card supports. The driver may not implement compatibility profiles, in which case you must limit yourself to the ***core*** profile specification. Otherwise, you will access to legacy stuff. There are two versions of the OpenGL specification beginning with GL 3.1 for precisely this reason.

Comment: It is to be noted that the SuperBible sticks to core profile only. This is written upfront in the Introduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions which are part of OpenGL 3.3 are listed in [its man pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/). If the function talked about in the book is not listed in this, then that function would be part of OpenGL 4 or above. The man pages strictly have only what is absoluted mandated for that particular version of OpenGL. [OpenGL 4 man pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) are also there to verify against.

Another resource is [OpenGL 3.2 reference card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl-quick-reference-card.pdf) which lists them neatly. You can compare it with the [4.3 reference card](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl43-quick-reference-card.pdf) to know the difference.

Above all OpenGL is an open specification, so you are free to look up the [OpenGL 3.3 specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec33.core.20100311.withchanges.pdf) to confirm some assumption if you want to be just sure.